# what is flow of this zend update statement

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, sql-update

I know that this statement updates the record in the zend framework. But I want to understand the complete flow of this statement. Statement is

```
$request->update($data,$request->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?',$this->getRequest()->getParam('selected_id'))) )
```

`$data` is the array of records that is passed to it and `$request` is the object of model. I want to know whole meaning of this statement

Comment: naming DbModel variable $request is really bad practice :)

Comment: @Tomas Fejfar Thanks dude for your suggestion but what is good practice?

Comment: it was kind of a joke (insider joke to be precise) :) $request and $response are usually Request and Response object (meaning HTTP request and response). You should name it so, that it resembles the contents and not colide with common objects (db, registry, request, ...).

Comment: Everyone usually thinks, that if a variable is called $request, it holds Zend_Http_Request... ;)

Comment: @Tomas Fejfar... Nice point, I'll take care of it.. Actually I am having a Request Management Module within a system, that's why I named it so... But good point raised by you.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know update statement uses `$table->update($data, $where);`

`$request` is db table model. `->getAdapter` gets the [**adapter**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html).

Also `quoteInto()` is best defined as by documentation

> The most typical usage of quoting is to interpolate a PHP variable into a SQL expression or statement. You can use the quoteInto() method to do this in one step. This method takes two arguments: the first argument is a string containing a placeholder symbol (?), and the second argument is a value or PHP variable that should be substituted for that placeholder.

And the last expression `$this->getRequest()->getParam('selected_id')`.

`$this->getRequest()` gets the request `$_GET` type

And `getParam('selected_id'))` fetches `selected_id` of `GET` object.